# Jquery data-role="collapsible" aren't being captured

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Please see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/6/)

Why aren't the Jquery data-role="collapsible" being captured in this case ?

This is what i have tried:

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" class="my-collaspible"><h3>'+name+' <a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon "></a></h3></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function () {
        alert('Expanded');
    });
    $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsiblecollapse', function () {
        alert('Collapsed');
    });
});
```

This is my code

```
<head>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>‌​
        <!--<script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>-->
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/additional-methods.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom/search.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom/url.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function () {
      alert('Expanded');
      console.log('sss');
     });

     $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function()
     {
       alert('Collapsed');
     });


     $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapsibleexpand', function () {
        alert("Expanded");
      });

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:-

```
$('.my-collaspible').bind('expand', function () {
  alert('Expanded');
 });

 $('.my-collaspible').bind('collapse', function()
 {
   alert('Collapsed');
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/znz17ctm/7/)

Comment: This is working under the fiddle , but i don't have any idea why it isn't working if i run the same under my application .

Comment: Thanks for the answer , Any reason why it isn't working for me in the Application ?? i have kept this under the document ready itself .

Comment: @PreethiJain check your browser console do you have any other error?

Comment: Ya , i have checked that but didn't find anything under browser console .

Comment: which jquery version you are using?

Comment: I am using <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

Comment: I mean main jquery file i.e jquery.min.js if you are not loading try to add this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have included this , but still no luck . the same thing , and i cant see anything under my browser console .

Comment: I have edited my question and added my code , please see that .